# How do you extract CSS code from a pandoc theme file?

Tags: html, css, json, pandoc

By typing the code

```sh
pandoc --print-highlight-style breezedark > breezedark.theme
```

I got the `breezedark` highlight-style theme file from `pandoc`. However, I want this theme to be in the `CSS` format.

I've been searching an answer for this question for a while and didn't find an answer. How can I do that?

I was able to get a fraction of the `CSS` file in a round-about way. I wrote a sample `markdown` file, and converted that into a html file using the command

```sh
pandoc CPP.md -s --highlight-style breezedark -o temp.html"
```

and from the header of this `temp.html` file, I got a fraction of the `CSS` code.

How can I extract the full CSS equivalent of a pandoc theme file in a more direct way? Any ideas?

My `pandoc` version is `pandoc 2.2.3.2`.

Comment: There is no way more direct than what you found.

Comment: @tarleb do you know if skylight uses a library to convert the highlighter XML to CSS? I searched the pandoc and skylight repos and found no CSS which makes me think this, but this is a really brittle manual process 